# Trimming powershell objects

Tags: powershell

I am using the powershell following command

```
Get-RdsSessionHost -TenantName "api" -HostPoolName "vvt"|Select-Object SessionHostName 

and the results I get is
wvdpd24.api.com.au
wvdpd25.api.com.au
wvdpd1.api.com.au

now I want to remove the part ".api.com.au"
How do i do this, any idea guys?
```

Comment: `(Get-RdsSessionHost -TenantName "api" -HostPoolName "vvt"|Select-Object SessionHostName).Replace(".api.com.au","")`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`-replace` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.2#replacement-operator). It has the following syntax.

```
<input> -replace <regular-expression>, <substitute>
```

In this case the `<regular-expression>` should be `".api.com.au$"`(As we want to match `api.com.au` at the end of the string). So your final code should look like this,

```
Get-RdsSessionHost -TenantName "api" -HostPoolName "vvt" |Select-Object SessionHostName | ForEach-Object {$_.SessionHostName -replace "\.api\.com\.au$", ""}
```

Comment: `-replace` uses regex, so you need to escape the dots `'\.api\.com\.au$'`

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways of doing this of course.

Using `-split`:

```
(Get-RdsSessionHost -TenantName "api" -HostPoolName "vvt").SessionHostName | ForEach-Object { ($_ -split '\.')[0] }
```

Using `-replace`

```
(Get-RdsSessionHost -TenantName "api" -HostPoolName "vvt").SessionHostName | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace '\.api\.com\.au$' }
```

or

```
(Get-RdsSessionHost -TenantName "api" -HostPoolName "vvt").SessionHostName | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace '\.\w+\.\w+\.\w+$' }
```

or

```
(Get-RdsSessionHost -TenantName "api" -HostPoolName "vvt").SessionHostName | ForEach-Object { ($_ -replace '^([^\.]+).*', '$1') }
```

Where the above uses regex operators `-split` and `-replace`, you could also use String methods where no escaping needs to be done:

```
(Get-RdsSessionHost -TenantName "api" -HostPoolName "vvt").SessionHostName | ForEach-Object { $_.Split(".")[0] }
```

or

```
(Get-RdsSessionHost -TenantName "api" -HostPoolName "vvt").SessionHostName | ForEach-Object { $_.Replace(".api.com.au","") }
```

or even

```
(Get-RdsSessionHost -TenantName "api" -HostPoolName "vvt").SessionHostName | ForEach-Object { $_.Substring(0, $_.IndexOf(".")) }
```